# Simple group with Klein four Sylow

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> If $G$ is a simple group, with a Sylow $2$-subgroup isomorphic to the Klein four group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, then I want to show that any two involutions in a given Sylow $2$-subgroup are conjugate in $G$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: A solution/method in relatively elementary terms would be appreciated — I am alright with some machinery as long as you explain it.

Comment: I think you need Burnside's Transfer Theorem to prove that. Do you know it?

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm afraid not. If you could explain it I would be happy to understand it as part of the solution.

Answer (score -7):

I think you gate this from Sylow's 2nd theorem

Comment: That tells you that the Sylow Subgroups are conjugate. This question is dealing with the elements inside a single Sylow Subgroup.